# Почему программа во всех процедурах выдает ноль при любых введенных числах?

Tags: массивы, pascal, процедуры

Программа во всех процедурах выдает ноль при любых введенных числах. Уже всё перепробовала. Что не так?

```
program weather;

uses crt;

var
  a:array [1..31] of integer;
  i,s,t,max,min:integer;

procedure sum;
begin
  read(i);
  s:=0;
  for i:=1 to 31 do
    s:=s+a[i];
  s:=s;
  writeln(s);
end;

procedure hot;
begin
  read(i);
  s:=0;
  for i:=1 to 31 do
    if (a[i]>0) then
      s:=s+1;
  writeln(s);
end;

procedure cold;
begin
  read(i);
  s:=0;
  for i:=1 to 31 do
    if (a[i]<0) then
      s:=s+1;
  writeln(s);
end;

procedure max_t;
begin
  read(i);
  max:=a[31];
  for i:=1 to 31 do
    if (a[i]>max) then
      max:=a[i];
  writeln(max);
end;

procedure min_t;
begin
  read(i);
  min:=a[31];
  for i:=1 to 31 do
    if (a[i]<min) then
      min:=a[i];
  writeln(min);
end;

begin
  sum;
  hot;
  cold;
  max_t;
  min_t;
end.
```

Comment: а где и как вы заполняете a?

Comment: [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1466535/edit) язык программирования в тегах. Кроме этого, добавьте в вопрос информацию о том, что вы подаете на вход программы и какой выход хотите получить?

Comment: Не ленитесь форматировать код

Answer (score 0):

в procedure sum вы для чего-то присваиваете в конце программы переменной s её же значение равное нулю и вы не присвоили значение элементам массива

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Проблема не в присваивании `s := s`, хотя оно лишнее, а в том, что массив `a` заполнен нулями по умолчанию и нет кода, который вводил бы данные о температуре.